# Set strict sql mode in peewee

Tags: python, mysql, peewee

I'd like to force ENUM constraints in my mySQL database. To do that, it is suggested I use "strict" sql mode. In an interactive prompt, this can be set with one of:

```
SET GLOBAL sql_mode = 'STRICT_ALL_TABLES';
SET SESSION sql_mode = 'STRICT_ALL_TABLES';
```

Or at server startup with:

```
 --sql-mode="STRICT_ALL_TABLES"
```

Or in `my.cnf` as:

```
sql-mode="STRICT_ALL_TABLES"
```

Is there a way to do such a thing in `peewee`? Perhaps by extending the `Database` class? Or injecting raw sql in queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is to probably subclass `MySQLDatabase` and override the `_connect()` method, e.g.

```
class StrictMySQLDatabase(MySQLDatabase):
    def _connect(self, database, **kwargs):
        conn = super(StrictMySQLDatabase, self)._connect(database, **kwargs)
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute("SET SESSION sql_mode = 'STRICT_ALL_TABLES';")
        return conn
```